# What is どうって in どうってことありません?

Tags: expressions, set-phrases, spoken-language

> どうってことありません。

I know it means "It was nothing."

But, what is どうって?

Comment: Need more context.「って」could be a colloquial topic marker.「どうって」could mean "speaking of how..."

Answer (score 7):

- どうってことない
- どうってことありません
- どうと言うこともない
- etc.

are all variations of a set phrase meaning "it's nothing" "it's no big deal". Here どう is just the usual question word and って or と the usual quoting particle. Literally the phrase means that it is not something you would ask/enquire about by saying どう.