# Understanding「もともと片親と言えどももう高校生。親と会えないからってどうという年齢でもなかった。」

Tags: grammar, meaning

From 義妹生活 - １話. 浅村 (who also have single father who is divorced) learned that 綾瀬 grew up with mother who is divorced who works at night everyday and rarely interact with each other. This is the reason 綾瀬 is cold and not good with people. The below is 浅村's thoughts.

> あまりにも大人びたドライな空気をまとっている理由が彼女の話を聞いているとなんとなくわかるような気がした。寂しがる気配が皆無なのは、孤独に慣れているからなのだろう。
>
> **もともと片親と言えどももう高校生。俺自身もそうだけど、親と会えないからってどうという年齢でもなかった。**

I have difficulty understanding the last part. I think「もともと片親と言えどももう高校生」refers to  綾瀬 and it means "Even though she have single parent in the beginning, she is already in high school"? What does it mean exactly?

For the second sentence, does そう refer to the fact that he is also a high school student? I think「親と会えないからってどうという年齢でもなかった」means "I'm no longer in age where I get worried because I can't meet my parents."? I'm not sure about the「からってどうという」part.

Comment: 「どうという～ない」-- Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/84440/9831

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've attempted to translate the sentences:

> Listening to her, I felt that I could somehow understand why she was wearing a too mature and dry air. The fact that she shows no sign of loneliness is probably because she is used to being alone.
>
> Even though she only had one parent to begin with, she is already a high school student. Like myself, both of us weren't at an age where it mattered that we couldn't see our parents.

Perhaps the author has the impression that at the age of high school students, they are no longer in the age to care much about whether they see their parents or not. On top of that, 綾瀬 has only one parent to begin with, and she has been in situations where her parent is absent (for example, as you have shown, she's away on business. In particular, in the case of 綾瀬's mother, she works at night, so 綾瀬 is at school during the day and cannot see her mother, and at night she cannot see her mother because her mother is at work), so she would have been used to this, so 浅村 thought that she was used to loneliness.

As for the part about "俺自身もそうだけど", as you indicated, it's referring to that 浅村 also has only one parent, and he is a high school student like 綾瀬.

Comment: Thanks, it's more clear than before! I wonder if から is redundant in the last sentence. Would「親と会えないってどうという年齢でもなかった」sound better?

Comment: @JimmyYang Actually sounds worse. 「親と会えないから**と言**って、どうという年齢でもなかった」would sound better while making it more understandable, I think.

Comment: Hmm, I still don't understand why から(と言)って is necessary.

Comment: @JimmyYang Maybe this will clear your issue? [【JLPT N２】文法・例文：〜からといって](https://nihongokyoshi-net.com/2019/02/27/jlptn2-grammar-karatoitte/)

Comment: So the last sentence should be parsed as「(親と会えないからと言って、どう) という年齢でもなかった」? It would literally mean "We are not in age where 'Just because we couldn't see our parents...' matters."

Comment: @JimmyYang Yeah, that looks fine to me.